# Start up (boot) menu doesn't show other linux distro

Tags: arch-linux, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I've installed arch using https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners_Guide I have x64 system with Ubuntu installed already and UEFI. There were no errors during the installation. However, after reboot the start up menu showed me only Ubuntu. I wonder, what might be the cause?

Here is what I have:
[image]

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1         1050624   382824447   190886912   83  Linux
/dev/sda2   *        2048     1050623      524288    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda3       382826494  1953523711   785348609    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sda5      1946028032  1953523711     3747840   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       382834688  1946025983   781595648   83  Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, your Ubuntu's GRUB isn't updated since you've added another OS. Issue the following command from the Ubuntu terminal emulator:

```
sudo update-grub
```